# Adding and removing dynamic controls Windows Forms using C#

Tags: c#, winforms, dynamic-controls

I have three Tabs in my Windows Forms form. Depending on the selected RadioButton in the `TabPages[0]`, I added few dynamic controls on the relevant TabPage. On the `Button_Click` event the controls are added, but the problem is I'm not able to remove the dynamically added controls from the other (irrelevant) TabPage.

Here's my code:

```
Label label235 = new Label();
TextBox tbMax = new TextBox();
label235.Name = "label235";
tbMax.Name = "txtBoxNoiseMax";
label235.Text = "Noise";
tbMax.ReadOnly = true;
label235.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
tbMax.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
label235.Size = new Size(74, 13);
tbMax.Size = new Size(85, 20);

if (radioButton1.Checked)
{
    label235.Location = new Point(8, 476);
    tbMax.Location = new Point(138, 473);

    tabControl.TabPages[1].Controls.Add(label235);
    tabControl.TabPages[1].Controls.Add(tbMax);

    tabControl.TabPages[2].Controls.RemoveByKey("label235");
    tabControl.TabPages[2].Controls.RemoveByKey("tbMax");
}
else
{
    label235.Location = new Point(8, 538);
    tbMax.Location = new Point(138, 535);

    tabControl.TabPages[1].Controls.RemoveByKey("label235");
    tabControl.TabPages[1].Controls.RemoveByKey("tbMax");

    tabControl.TabPages[2].Controls.Add(label235);
    tabControl.TabPages[2].Controls.Add(tbMax);
}
```

Where am I making that mistake?

Comment: have you tried debugging the application. What hapens to the Controls list before and after the RemoveByKey?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `tbMax`'s name is not "tbMax", but "txtBoxNoiseMax". So for one, it won't be able to find the TextBox on `RemoveByKey`.

You're making new controls each time.

Answer (score 0):

As lc already mentioned:

You named your TextBox variable `tbMax`, but you gave it the name *txtBoxNoiseMax*. If you take a look into the description of [RemoveByKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.removebykey.aspx), you'll see it works on the *Name* property. So you should change

```
tbMax.Name = "txtBoxNoiseMax";
```

into

```
tbMax.Name = "tbMax";
```