# Add the controls in runtime from XML in windows c#

Tags: c#, xml, hashtable

I have a tool which looks for phrases in a document and gives the count. I have those phrases in xml. I am using hashtable concept for this. I keep getting more and more phrases to add to xml every time. So now i want the controls to be created whn i add a phrase to xml at runtime. My UI has check boxex for each phrase where i can check whichever phrase i want to. I dint find any example relevent to this. Here is part of the code where i use my phrases.

```
Hashtable _optionTable = null;
            Hashtable _optionOccuranceTable = null;
            if (optionBox.Checked == true)
                ProcessNode(usrXmldoc, "Option", out _optionTable, out _optionOccuranceTable, oWord, oDoc);



                            Hashtable _QualityPhraseTable = null;
            Hashtable _QualityPhraseOccuranceTable = null;
            if (qualityBox.Checked == true)
                ProcessNode(usrXmldoc, "QualityPhrase", out _QualityPhraseTable, out _QualityPhraseOccuranceTable, oWord, oDoc);


            Hashtable _DirectiveTable = null;
            Hashtable _DirectiveOccuranceTable = null;
            if (directiveBox.Checked == true)
                ProcessNode(usrXmldoc, "Directive", out _DirectiveTable, out _DirectiveOccuranceTable, oWord, oDoc);


             Hashtable _ContinuanceTable = null;
            Hashtable _ContinuanceOccuranceTable = null;
            if (continuanceBox.Checked == true)
                ProcessNode(usrXmldoc, "Continuance", out _ContinuanceTable, out _ContinuanceOccuranceTable, oWord, oDoc);



                            This is the XML part



   string usrXmlConfigFile = CurrentDirectory + "\\Dictionary.xml";
   FileStream usrFs = new FileStream(usrXmlConfigFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read,
                           FileShare.ReadWrite);
    XmlDocument usrXmldoc = new XmlDocument();
                    usrXmldoc.Load(usrFs);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to know whenever the xml file has changed, as in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/721714/notification-when-a-file-changes).

The read and parse the xml file, as in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604330/c-sharp-xml-parsing-read-a-simple-xml-file-and-retrieve-values).

Finally, add controls dinamically in winforms, as in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688915/adding-removing-dynamic-controls-in-c-sharp-winforms).

Comment: I need help in writing the condition like If a new root node is added to xml then get the root name and create dynamic controls on UI.

Comment: I suggest you to edit your question with some code showing what have you tried so far.